# Why is replicateM (length xs) m way more efficient than sequenceA (fmap (const m) xs)?

Tags: performance, haskell, optimization, memory, monads

My two submissions for a programming problem differ in just one expression (where `anchors` is a nonempty list and `(getIntegrals n)` is a state monad):

[Submission 1](https://codeforces.com/contest/1534/submission/134660093). `replicateM (length anchors - 1) (getIntegrals n)`

[Submission 2](https://codeforces.com/contest/1534/submission/134660047). `sequenceA $ const (getIntegrals n) <$> tail anchors`

The two expressions' equivalence should be easy to see at compile time itself, I guess. And yet, [comparatively](https://codeforces.com/submissions/cobra2020) the `sequenceA` one is slower, and more importantly, takes up >10x memory:

| Code | Time | Memory |
| --- | --- | --- |
| replicateM one | 732 ms | 22200 KB |
| sequenceA one | 1435 ms | 262100 KB |

<sup>(with "Memory limit exceeded on test 4" error for the second entry, so it might be even worse).</sup>

Why is it so?

It is becoming quite hard to predict which optimizations are automatic and which are not!

EDIT: As suggested, pasting [Submission 1](https://codeforces.com/contest/1534/submission/134660093) code below. In this interactive problem, the 'server' has a hidden tree of size `n`. Our code's job is to find out that tree, with minimal number of queries of the form `? k`. Loosely speaking, the server's response to `? k` is the row corresponding to node `k` in the <strike>adjacency</strike> distance matrix of the tree. Our choices of `k` are: initially `1`, and then a bunch of nodes obtained from `getAnchors`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Safe #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 #-}

import Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B8
import qualified Data.ByteString.Builder as Bu
import Data.Functor.Identity
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import Data.ByteString.Builder.Extra (flush) 
import System.IO

type St = StateT [B8.ByteString] Identity

solve :: St Bu.Builder
solve = do
  n <- getIntegral
  ds <- getIntegrals n  -- get the first row of adjacency matrix
  let
    anchors = getAnchors ds
    readFirst = if head anchors==1 then return ds else getIntegrals n
    readRest = replicateM (length anchors - 1) (getIntegrals n) -- get some other rows too
  adjss <- liftA2 (:) readFirst readRest  
  let
    adj1ss = [map snd $ filter ((1==).fst) (zip adjs [1..]) | adjs <- adjss]
    s0 = Bu.string7
    snl = Bu.string7 "\n" <> flush
    i0 = Bu.intDec
    printEdge src dst = i0 src <> s0 " " <> i0 dst <> snl
    printAdj (src,dsts) = mconcat [printEdge src dst | dst<-dsts]
    printAdjs = mconcat $ printAdj <$> zip anchors adj1ss
    ask k = s0 "? " <> i0 k <> snl
    askRest = mconcat $ ask <$> (dropWhile (==1) anchors)
  return $ ask 1 <> askRest <> s0 "!" <> snl <> printAdjs

getAnchors :: [Int]->[Int]
getAnchors xs = reverse $ go (zip xs [1..]) [] [] where
  go [] odds evens = if length odds < length evens then odds else evens
  go ((k,i):rest) odds evens
    | even k = go rest odds (i: evens)
    | odd k = go rest (i: odds) evens
 
getByteString :: St B8.ByteString
getByteString = state getNext where
  getNext [] =  (B8.take 0 (B8.pack "."),[])
  getNext (w:ws) =  (w,ws)
 
getIntegral :: Num t => St t
getIntegral  = convertToNum <$> getByteString where
  convertToNum x =  fromIntegral $ fromMaybe 0 $ liftA fst $ B8.readInteger x
 
getIntegrals :: Num t => Int -> St [t]
getIntegrals n = replicateM n getIntegral

main :: IO ()
main = do
  hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
  bytestrings <- B8.words <$> B8.getContents
  B8.putStr $ Bu.toLazyByteString $ evalState solve bytestrings
```

Comment: Can you show a bit more code here, to make the question self-contained?

Comment: Ah, ok, deleted my answer. Sorry, I didn't read careful enough. I'm probably wrong then and the problem has to be related not to an aditional traversal of the list, but that the intermediate list of [St _] is not optimized away.

Comment: Weird: Copy&pasting into Submission 1 the definition of `replicateM` from base ([link](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.html#replicateM)) leads to the same bad behaviour of Submission 2. I don't see any rewrite rules that might be the cause for this. See code [here](https://codeforces.com/contest/1534/submission/134758661). Discovered this trying to manually inline replicateM which also lead to the same behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is related to inlining. I do not understand it completly, but here is what I understand.

## Inlining

First we find that copy&pasting the [definition of `replicateM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.html#replicateM) into the Submission 1 yields the same bad performance as Submission 2 ([submission](https://codeforces.com/contest/1534/submission/134758661)). However if we replace the `INLINABLE` pragma of `replicateM` with a `NOINLINE` pragma things work again ([submission](https://codeforces.com/contest/1534/submission/134759930)).

The `INLINABLE` pragma on `replicateM` is different from an `INLINE` pragma, the latter leading to more inlining than the former. Specifically here if we define `replicateM` in the same file Haskells heuristic for inlining decides to inline, but with `replicateM` from base it decides against inlining in this case even in the presence of the `INLINABLE` pragma.

`sequenceA` and `traverse` on the other hand both have `INLINE` pragmas leading to inlining. Taking a hint from the above experiment we can define a non-inlinable `sequenceA` and indead this makes Solution 2 work ([submission](https://codeforces.com/contest/1534/submission/134760643)).

```hs
{-# NOINLINE sequenceA' #-}
sequenceA' :: [St x] -> St [x]
sequenceA' = sequenceA
```

## What is going wrong?

*The following is some pretty severe speculation on my part.*

But how does inlining cause problems? Well let's look at the difference between the following two core dumps

*With inlining:*
[image: With inlining]

*Without inlining:*
[image: Without inlining]

Here we're looking both times at what corresponds to, in the first instance the inlined part and the second instance the actual call to replicateM.

```hs
readRest = replicateM (length anchors - 1) (getIntegrals n)
```

Now the interesting bit is that in the inlined code the yellow highlighted lines are run in every loop of `replicateM`, while in the non-inlined part they are calculated once, outside the lambda abstraction which is passed to `replicateM`.

But what are they doing? There are multiple variables called `ds` in the core, but this one refers to this:

[image]

which in turn corresponds to

```hs
solve = do
  n <- getIntegral
```

So what I think is happening is that instead of running `getIntegral` once and saving the result, it's starting state is saved and it is rerun with this state for every pass of the loop. Indeed changing this line to the following (requires BangPatterns language extension) fixes all versions ([submission](https://codeforces.com/contest/1534/submission/134781099)).

```hs
solve = do
  !n <- getIntegral
```

I'm still not really sure, but this is my best guess.

Here are the two core dumps for reference: [Inline](https://gist.github.com/juliapath/380bbd7b2e085431d416b0b030865cb3#file-inline-hs),
[Noinline](https://gist.github.com/juliapath/380bbd7b2e085431d416b0b030865cb3#file-noinline-hs)

## This is crazy

Well yes, but I feel that the underlying problem here is your use of lazy IO and lazy State. Using the strict State transformer Haskell probably would have figured out to not keep old state around (I have no idea, just a guess), however we can not use strict State here, because of your reliance on lazy IO, i.e. getting all the input at the beginning using `getContents` and lazyly forcing it while making sure to provide output before forcing too much. Instead it would be a lot safer to explicitely read the input line by line. I.e. replace the `StateT [ByteString]` with `IO` or something more fancy like a `Conduit` or `Pipe`.

Comment: Any chance you could add accessible (text-based) core dumps, and also providing ones that show enough uniques to make sense? I'm not convinced `getIntegral` is being run multiple times; it would seem to be accessing the saved `ds` value. BTW, I totally agree that using lazy I/O and lazy `StateT` is likely the root of the problem; that's just not a good plan.

Comment: @dfeuer I have added links to two core dumps to the end of „What is going wrong“ section. I'm also not really convinced. Maybe you can take a look, in which case good luck :)

Comment: FWIW, I don't think anything fancy would really be helpful (though I guess you *could* encode it as a bidirectional pipe, i.e., `Proxy`). If my imagined solution is correct, I'd do something like `class MonadQuery m where query :: Int -> m (PrimArray Int)` and work mostly under `(MonadQuery m, MonadWriter [(Int, Int)] m)`. I'd probably instantiate `m` to `Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.CPS.WriterT [(Int, Int)] IO`. Of course, if the problem size is big enough for concurrent computation to be worthwhile, then the writer arrangement will need to be changed, but I don't think that's likely the case.

Comment: Admittedly I don't completely understand the core dump part but hopefully one day I will, and thanks to your answer, I now know to inspect pragmas in such situations. Regarding lazy IO: my thought was to hide the line-by-line structure, since what matters to the core algorithm is just a sequence of integers. Isn't such a separation in line with Haskell philosophy? Like, in a hypothetical scenario where the input is 3 lines each having 2000 Ints, and my solution needs to read, say, 3 Ints at a time.

Comment: Sorry, I guess that should probably be `Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.CPS.WriterT (Data.Semigroup.Dual [(Int, Int)]) IO`.

Comment: @cobra, I don't really think this problem naturally has any interesting *state*, per se. I don't understand how your solution works, but the way I imagine solving it starts with a list of tree levels (obtained from the result of the first query, `? 1`), and recursively breaks that down into subproblems. Each subproblem produces its share of the edges, naturally represented in `MonadWriter`. In the process of doing so, it may need to perform queries, which of course shouldn't be tied to `IO` or lines or anything at that level. But they actually *will* perform `IO` when run, and that's fine.

Comment: @cobra, like I said, I don't understand your algorithm (such as why you care about even levels vs. odd levels), but you have recursion within your `getAnchors` function. The way I imagine it: once you get the result of `? 1`, you can generate a "root" node (1) and a list of levels: `(Int, [NonEmpty Int])`. From this you can immediately produce all the edges connected to 1. Now you're all done with 1. What's next? Separate out a subtree. Separate out the first node of the first level, query on it, and (roughly speaking) `partition` the tree into nodes that are closer to that node (cont)

Comment: (cont) than to the front of the levels list and ones that are further. Now you've divided the problem in two pieces; solve each piece. Throughout, you'll have to be careful to deal efficiently with the special case of a level with exactly one element. You should probably use a custom implementation of `NonEmpty`: `data NonEmpty a = Cons a (NonEmpty a) | One a` or so.

Comment: @dfeuer Input to `getAnchors` is the distance vector of node 1 (root). The `go` function partitions the nodes into ones that are at even distance from the root (called `evens`) and ones that are odd distance from the root (`odds`). Subsequently, it is enough to only query (`ask`) for `evens` nodes (or `odds`, whichever is smaller in number) because every edge in the tree connects an even level node with an odd level node.

Comment: @cobra „my thought was to hide the line-by-line structure, since what matters to the core algorithm is just a sequence of integers“. Yeah you can do that, that's fine, the problem is, that the input is supplied only in response to queries of yours, but you have just neatly hidden that away too, pretending like you had access to all of the input from the beginning. Now forcing more of the input, an action that is supposed to be pure, triggers some IO. This is called lazy IO and is generally considered to be not such a good idea. It makes it hard to predict when or if IO actions are executed.